# Hide given input types when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have a form consisting of some input types. When checkbox is not checked, I want all of other input types  to disappear and reappear when checkbox is checked.Could you help me  with this please? Here is my code:

```
  <form id='sample' action='sample.php' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/><br>
 <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br>
 <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
 <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Hide all!<br>
  <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

Comment: BTW you should atleast try something and then ask about problems.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){

$('input[name=vehicle]').on('change', function(){

if(this.checked){
  $('#sample').find('input').not(this).hide();
}
  else{
  $('#sample').find('input').not(this).show();
}

})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='sample' action='sample.php' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/><br>
 <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br>
 <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
 <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Hide all!<br>
  <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much vinayakj. This was what I wanted.Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggle()` method.

```js
$('input[name=vehicle]').on('change', function(){
  $('#sample input[type=text], input[type=password]').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='sample' action='sample.php' method='post'>
   <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/><br>
   <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label>
   <input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br>
   <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
   <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br>
   <label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
   <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br>
   <label for='password' >Password*:</label>
   <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br>
   
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Hide all!<br>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you also want to hide the label, submit button, so I hide all.

If no, you can add a filter to exclude it.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var shouldHide = !$(this).is(':checked');
    // Hide all except
    $(this).siblings('label, input').toggle(shouldHide);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='sample' action='sample.php' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/><br>
 <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br>
 <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br>

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
 <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Hide all!<br>
  <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

Comment: That is what I am in need of.Thank you very much fuyushimoya!

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide the div containing all the text fields and labels see code below:

```
 <form id='sample' action='sample.php' method='post'>
 <div id="tests">
 <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/><br>
 <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label>
 <input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br>
 <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
 <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br>

 <label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
 <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br>

 <label for='password' >Password*:</label>
 <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br>
       </div>
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="test()" id="seeCheck"> Hide all!<br>
 <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form> 

<script>
    function test(){
       if (document.getElementById('seeCheck').checked) {

        document.getElementById("tests").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("tests").style.display = 'block';
    }
    }
</script>
```

Heres the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mgqptmt8/11/

Hope this helps.